# how to change the rows value by condition on a column (python,pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hey all i want to change the rows by condition on a column.

so where column "type"==A

i want the cols [col1-col5] will be 1 if the value
is biger 2

else i like the value to be 0

```
the DATA 
data={"col1":[np.nan,3,4,5,9,2,6],
"col2":[4,2,4,6,0,1,5],
"col3":[7,6,0,11,3,6,7],
"col4":[14,11,22,8,6,np.nan,9],
"col5":[0,5,7,3,8,2,9],
"type":["A","A","C","A","B","A","E"],
"number":["one","two","two","one","one","two","two"]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

How I expect the data to be

```
data={"col1":[0,1,4,1,9,0,6],
      "col2":[1,0,4,1,0,0,5],
      "col3":[1,1,0,1,3,1,7],
      "col4":[1,1,22,1,6,0,9],
      "col5":[0,1,7,1,1,0,9],
      "type":["A","A","C","A","B","A","E"],
      "number":["one","two","two","one","one","two","two"]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by condition equal `A` and columns between first and last column name, then compare for greater like [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html), for map `True, False` to `1,0` is used convert mask to integers, last update by [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.loc[df['type'].eq('A'), 'col1':'col5'].gt(2).astype(int))
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 type number
0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    A    one
1   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    A    two
2   4.0   4.0   0.0  22.0   7.0    C    two
3   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    A    one
4   9.0   0.0   3.0   6.0   8.0    B    one
5   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0    A    two
6   6.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   9.0    E    two
```

Or by assign back:

```
m = df['type'].eq('A')
df.loc[m, 'col1':'col5'] = df.loc[m, 'col1':'col5'].gt(2).astype(int)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 type number
0   0.0     1     1   1.0     0    A    one
1   1.0     0     1   1.0     1    A    two
2   4.0     4     0  22.0     7    C    two
3   1.0     1     1   1.0     1    A    one
4   9.0     0     3   6.0     8    B    one
5   0.0     0     1   0.0     0    A    two
6   6.0     5     7   9.0     9    E    two
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to get all `type` `A` rows, then use `df._get_numeric_data`/[`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)(`'number'`) to get all numeric fields, then use [`df.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and cast them as int using [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), now update the DataFrame with new values using [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
df.update(df.query('type == "A"')._get_numeric_data().gt(2).astype(int))
                                #.select_dtypes('number')
df

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 type number
0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0    A    one
1   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    A    two
2   4.0   4.0   0.0  22.0   7.0    C    two
3   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    A    one
4   9.0   0.0   3.0   6.0   8.0    B    one
5   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0    A    two
6   6.0   5.0   7.0   9.0   9.0    E    two
```